# How to pause/freeze the AR Camera in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore, pause

I am making an AR game with Unity.

I used the commonly used 'Time.timeScale = 1' to use the pause function,
This will turn the AR Camera screen into a black screen.

In addition, if you add the ar occlusion manager function in this state, the app will be down with the screen bugged.

When using AR Camera, what is the proper way to implement temporary suspension?
The actual screen you are viewing with AR camera should be seen with a frozen frame.

Please

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is take a camera shot

```
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("TestImage.png");
```

then i would display it on a raw image

```
RawImage qrRenderer;
renderer.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
```

you can at that time disable youe camera

```
camera.enabled = false;
```